# Angular Modal ng-click does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have made a modal in angular, it pops up great but the exit button doesnt fire to close the modal. It works if the button to open is reclicked but adding a new button inside the modal does not fire the function. Btw there is no bootstrap in this.

```
    <section  class="modal" ng-show="showMenu">
    <div ng-click="setActive(album)">
    <p class="exit" ng-click="modalFunc()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
    <h1>{{albumMod.artist}} - {{albumMod.title}}</h1>
    <ul class="tracks">
      <span><img src={{albumMod.img}}></span>
      <li>Album: {{albumMod.album}}</li>
      <li>Price: $1.29</li>
    </ul>
    <form style="display: inline" action="/#cart" method="get">
      <button ng-click="setActive(album); cartFunc()" id="{{album.id}}"><a>Add</a></button>
  </form>

  </div>
</section>


     $scope.closeMenu=true;
 $scope.showMenu=false;
 $scope.showItems=false;

 $scope.modalFunc= function(){
   $scope.showMenu = !$scope.showMenu;
   console.log($scope.selected);
   $scope.showItems = !$scope.showItems;
   $scope.closeMenu=!$scope.closeMenu;
   // console.log($scope.selected.attr("id"));
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.showMenu flag which you have used to hide popup is not used correctly. When $scope.modalFunc method is called then you negate the value of $scope.showMenu and assigned. So after assignment, $scope.showMenu value will be true. 
Now you have used ng-show="showMenu" so your popup will not be hide.

Correct code will be:

```
1. Set $scope.showMenu = true in the callback which called when popup is opened.

2. $scope.modalFunc= function(){
   $scope.showMenu = !$scope.showMenu;
...
}

3. Remove $scope.showMenu=false; since it is not needed.
```

Comment: My problem isnt whether the modal shows or hides its that the ng-click in <p class="exit"> never fires. I can tell it's not fireing because it does not console.log() anything even though it should when running the modalFunc function.